# WPF - Canvas won't update when BackgroundWorker is completed

Tags: wpf, multithreading, user-interface, canvas

I need to update my Canvas when BackgroundWorker is completed. When i update the Canvas through a button actionlistener it works perfect. But when i call my update function when backroundWorker is completed. The gui won't update.

The function that add items to the canvas:

```
public void AddItemsToCanvas()
    {

       int factor = 0;

       cvList.Children.Clear();
       foreach (ItemControl item in ItemControl.ItemsList)
       {

           cvList.Children.Add(item.updateName);
           Canvas.SetLeft(item.updateName, 13);
           Canvas.SetTop(item.updateName, factor + 10);
           Canvas.SetZIndex(item.updateName, 1);

           cvList.Children.Add(item.imageButton);
           Canvas.SetLeft(item.imageButton, 180);
           Canvas.SetTop(item.imageButton, factor + 13);
           Canvas.SetZIndex(item.imageButton, 5);}}
```

The button that calls the update function:

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        updateCanvas();
    }

    public void updateCanvas()
    {
            Service serv = new Service();
            serv.SuperlinkCompartments();

            //Check for updates and add them to a List of updates
            Update up = new Update();
            up.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(Items_PropertyChanged);
            up.ShowUpdates();      
    }

    public void Items_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        AddItemsToCanvas();
    }
```

The Canvas updates perfectly when called from the button actionListener. But not working when the UpdateCanvas() is called from the BackgroundWorker event.

```
public void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = dic3[(BackgroundWorker)sender];
        int index = (int)item.controlButton.Tag;
        item.Progressbar.Value = 0;

        SystemInfo.SystemList[Update.UpdateList[index].SystemIndex].Version = Update.UpdateList[index].UpdateVersion;


        lvSystems.ItemsSource = SystemInfo.SystemList;

        updateCanvas();

    }
```

I'm i missing something in the BackgroundWorker event function?

Comment: i've tried to include Dispatcher.BeginInvoke in my code. But can't make it to work.

Answer (score 0):

try using the `Dispatcher':

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(()=>
{
    updateCanvas();
}), DispatcherPriority.Render);
```

then, inside your `updateCanvas()` method, add the following at the end:

```
cvList.UpdateLayout();
```

Comment: do you have other suggestions @d.moncada ?

Comment: @user3000138 added an update. Try using Application.Current.Dispatcher inside your backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted method, then at the end of your updateCanvas(), add the UpdateLayout

Comment: Still not working. I think i have a threading issue somewhere. @d.moncada

Comment: interesting.. when is the background worker getting called, and when? Also, why are you using a background worker?

Comment: The background.RunWorkerAsync is called from a button located inside my canvas. The actionListener for my button is located in the MainWindow. I also initialize my backround worker from the button actionListener. I'm using Background worker to report progress in a progressbar. It's a function that extracts some files and copy them to different locations. The only purpose i'm using it for reporting the progress and because it can be a long process that i don't want it to block for my UI thread. d.moncada

Comment: Shall the backgroundWorker completed and progressChanged not run in the UI thread? @d.moncada

Comment: progressChanged needs to run on the UI thread to update the progressbar. though, it's a bit hard to help if there is no real code example that I can work from so that I can re-produce the behavior myself